# Parse all equations in eps file

Tags: graphics, equations, parsing, psfrag

When I draw figures with a vector graphic program I can
export them as .eps files.
I know it is possible to use `psfrag` to replace given text
in the eps file with another text which is then parsed in LaTeX.

But to do this, one needs to do a separate definition for each replacement that should occur.
Is it possible that this replacement is done automatically for all
equations which are enclosed by `$`?

So every time there is a text surrounded by `$` in a given .eps file it should be parsed by Latex to correctly typeset the equations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which vector graphic program do you use? Some programs have explicit eps+latex exports that might help you.

Comment: I am using Adobe Illustrator, as far as I know there is no latex export option.